# Template engine

Tags: php, mvc

I've just completed coding my template engine. I'm willing to have a review on how to increase the quality, efficiency, elegance and performance of the code, perhaps by shortening the code, etc. I'm also open for suggestions on other ways of doing this. It would be really appreciated if you point out every tiny bit of things, as I am willing to modify and improve the code accordingly.

**`Model` class:**

```
<?php
class Model {
    public $site_url;
    public $theme;
    public $params;

    public function __construct($global) {
        $this->site_url = $global['site_url'];
        $this->theme    = $global['theme'];
    }
    public function createParam($key, $value) {
        $this->params['{' . $key . '}'] = $value;
    }
    public function replaceParams($content) {
        foreach($params as $key => $value) {
            str_replace($key, $value, $content);
        }
        return $content;
    }
}
```

**`View` class:**

```
<?php
class View {
    private $model;
    private $controller;

    public function __construct($model, $controller) {
        $this->model      = $model;
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }
    public function handlePageLoad($page_name) {
        $this->path = $model->site_url . "/app/tpl/skins/" . $model->theme . "/" . $page_name . ".php";
        if($controller->pageExists($this->path) === true) {
            $this->content = $controller->createPage($this->path);
            return $this->content;
        } else {
            $this->newPath = $model->site_url . "/app/tpl/skins/" . $model->theme . "/404.php";
            $this->content = $controller->createPage($this->path);
            header('Location: ' . $model->site_url . "/index.php?page=404");
            return $this->content;
        }
    }
}
```

**`Controller` class:**

```
<?php
class Controller {
    private $model;

    public function __construct($model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    public function pageExists($path) {
        if(file_exists($path)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function createPage($path) {
        $this->content = $model->replaceParams(file_get_contents($path));
        return $this->content;
    }
}
```

**Global.PHP**

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include "classes/class." . $class_name . ".php";
}

$global = array(
    'site_url' = 'http://localhost/Projects/HassanCMS',
    'theme'    = 'v1'
);

$model      = new Model($global);
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view       = new View($model, $controller);

$model->createParam('site_title', 'HassanTech');
```

Comment: OK, let's start with, the `Model` class is completely broken.  PHP has no implicit `$this`, so none of the code there gets or sets anything on the object.

Comment: What do you mean? @cHao

Comment: Oh wait yer, changed.

Comment: I mean that in PHP, you can't say `$property` -- you have to say `$this->property`.  So all the variables you ever set in that code, are local variables -- the code has no effect, and will probably emit notices.

Comment: @cHao I know, I confused it with a parameter.

Comment: Have you ever actually tried to use this code?

Comment: Yeah. I don't know why it did not show me that error.

Comment: Oh, error_reporting(0) was on.

Comment: @cHao Write an answer if you can make a review!

Comment: @AlexL: Working on it.  :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least two places in your code where it looks like you wanted to use an object's attributes, but you say `$attribute` rather than `$this->attribute`.  PHP requires `$this->` before property accesses.  If it's not there, PHP assumes there's a local variable.  Setting stuff that way will have no effect, and trying to read it will trigger a notice about undefined variables.  In fact, i'd be rather surprised if the code works at all.

But with the brokenness set aside, it looks like your three classes are quite confused about their jobs.  Let's review what each part of an MVC triad is supposed to do:

- The "view" basically handles all the rendering.
- The "model" represents the business objects, and should be the meat of the application.
- The "controller" coordinates stuff, routing stuff to the right place, etc.

Now, let's take a look at your classes.

- `View` tries to directly manage requests, doing the routing that the controller (or a router script) should be doing.
- `Model` is basically filling in a template.  That's part of the rendering, so that's the view's job.
- `Controller` barely does anything. It just tells the model to replace params, and determines whether a template exists.  It shouldn't be doing either one; that's the view's job.

As for why all that is bad: What happens if you want to use a template library like Twig or Smarty?  If your concerns were properly separated (ie: if everything were in the right place), you'd only have to change the `View` class.  Right now, though -- since rendering stuff is spread throughout the app -- you have to change everything.  This is why MVC was invented: to keep each part separate, so you can change one part without breaking the others.

Oh...and as i'm looking at it...it doesn't look like these scripts actually *do* anything.  `$view->handlePageLoad` never gets called.

---

Other possible issues:

- You're redirecting to a 404 page...and that page is probably not returning a 404 status code to the browser.  If Google ever finds a broken link to your site, it'd think that was the content...and your error page would end up indexed.

  Rather than redirecting, you could simply say `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');`, and print out the contents of your 404 page.
- `__autoload` is discouraged and [may be removed in future versions of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).  Instead, use [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to register an autoloader (which can be named whatever you like).  Then you can have more than one autoloader.  That will be very important later, when your site grows and you want to include other people's libraries, like Composer packages, which have their own autoloaders.

Comment: How can I send a 404 error code. Can you also simplify your language? I am finding it difficult to understand. I suck at english.

Comment: I've updated the code as you have suggested me. Please check the updated code here; http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57481/update-for-the-proper-way-of-using-the-mvc-concept

Answer (score 4):

#### MVC

The `handlePageLoad` method in `View` is doing a bit too much:

- It does checking if a page exists or not
- It knows too much about how the site works, the paths, the 404 page

I think it would be better if the `View` was dumber: each page of your site should have a corresponding `render_X` method, with the necessary parameters to render it. It should be the `Controller` to check if the requested link corresponds to a page that can be rendered (= *routing*).

#### Style

This method can be simplified:

> ```
> public function pageExists($path) {
>     if(file_exists($path)) {
>         return true;
>     } else {
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

like this:

```
public function pageExists($path) {
    return file_exists($path);
}
```

Actually, if you refactor the code to move the routing logic into the `Controller`, then the method will be pointless, as the `Controller` can simply call `file_exists` directly, and the other classes shouldn't need to know about a "pageExists" method.